# Creating a custom cursor for my website

Tags: css, cursor

I've never created a custom cursor before, and I'm having a little trouble with it. Maybe I'm doing this completely wrong, but I tried opening up an icon in photoshop, and saving it as .gif and .cur, but it still isn't working on my webpage. Does it need to be a specific size like the favicon? How would I go about doing this?

My code in the css:

```
body{
  cursor:url('cursor.gif'), pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image format should be icon (`.ico`). And the normal size should be 32x32.
But it depends on the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

See the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor%2Furl) on that. It says:

*In Gecko (Firefox) the limit of the cursor size is 128×128px. Larger cursor images are ignored. However, you should limit yourself to the size 32×32 for maximum compatibility with operating systems and platforms.*

Following image formats are supported:
[image]